# How to share a huge process among threads

Tags: jmeter

I have un deployment process for large number of apis.

I will get list of apis by querying a restservice which returns json response

```
{ "count" : 10000 ,[ {api_id:"1" , api_name:"xyz"},{api_id:"2",api_name:"abc"},....,{api_id:"999",api_name:"uuf"}]}
```

for each api id i need to perform some common undeploy ..

now with single thread this hole process is taking a long time.

I want to increase the threads hence the processing time get reduced.

currently my Thread group is shown below [click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbaOB.png) which run the process as expected , but i want to share this big task among threads , when thread-1 is doing undeploy of api_id 3  then thread-2 should not try to undeploy the same api_id 3 .since all threads are trying to access same data and try to do same process i am getting errors.

Now I am looking for a solution which doesn't have overriding issues and want to share the process.

I thought of sharing among threads like (1000/no of threads = chunck) and then for each thread start index is  0 to chunck   , chunk+1 to 2*chunck ...etc but i am unsure of implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have extracted your API id (or name) and you have 1000 variables like:

```
api_name_1=xyz
api_name_2=abc
api_name_3=uuf
```

You can just use [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function which increments each time it's being called so no matter how many threads you have each thread each iteration will pick up the next API to perform undeploy. Refer the next API name like:

```
 ${__V(api_name_${__counter(FALSE,)})}
```

[image: Counter functions]

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article for more information on different JMeter counter types and instructions on how to use them.